# java.io.EOFException[Could not read protocol type!]

Tags: java, hazelcast

We are working with hazelcast to replicate messages across jvms and we have two nodes in a cluster. We intermittently get this message in our logs:

> Exception : Connection [Address[192.168.6.25]:9002] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Could not read protocol type!]
>   jdk version (1.7.0_51), 
>   hazlecast.jar(hazelcast-3.2.3) 
>   vendor  (Oracle Corporation)

Wanted to know why this occurs. Can you please give us pointers?

Comment: I think still nothing is read, a kind of immediate end-of-file. Sorry.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Usually one starts with a brief description about the environment and the problem, not the error message. I recommend you to edit your question and change it accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the question .Please check

Comment: We are getting this EOF exception when it tries to join with other nodes in the cluster 
it looks like ReadHandler class and TcpIpConnection class of package com.hazelcast.nio generates this exception .When it tries to initializeSocketReader in the ReadHandler Class and when it tries to call the close method in the TcpIpConnection class we get this EOFexception.

Could we get a suggestion to avoid it